# m2eclipse doesn't reload pom.xml when switching git branch

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, m2eclipse, egit

I have git repo with two Maven projects which I have then imported as existing Maven project in Eclipse. Everything is working perfectly, until I try switching between branches with EGit in Eclipse.

pom.xml is not reloaded when switching branch, so while the file changes, Eclipse is still sees the old pom.xml which is very bad behavior. If I edit the file, such as add comment, and save, Eclipse correctly reloads the changed pom.xml. However, doing this every time I'm switching branches for all projects is tedious. Is there any workaround for this?

I have "Refresh resources when index changes" checked in EGit options, but that doesn't seem to help. Eclipse still refuses to reload pom.xml. Refresh doesn't help either.

Comment: That sounds like a problem in m2eclipse/m2e. Which version do you have installed?

Comment: I have Eclipse EE version that comes with m2eclipse, Version: Kepler Release, Build id: 20130614-0229

Comment: What happens when you change pom.xml outside of Eclipse and then refresh it in Eclipse? Does it cause the same problem? If yes, please [report a bug against m2e](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e).